# issue with muting and unmuting audio in a game

Tags: javascript, html

I'm building a 2D pacman clone (javascript and CSS) and i'm trying to add a background music with mute functionality. Two issues here. With audio.muted commented in i get `GET http://localhost:8080/favicon.ico 404 (Not Found).` I tried logging musicPlay and it doesn't switch between true/false. What is the best way to mute/unmute or pause? Also can anybody suggest good resources for creating ghosts? Most of the resources i found on git are old with inactive links. Thank you in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./dist/main.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="game-info">
        <div id="level">Level: 1</div>
        <div id="music">
            <audio autoplay src="./src/assets/music.mp3" type="mp3"></audio>
        </div>
        <div id="score">Score: 0</div>
    </div>
    <div id="body"></div>
    <div class="restart">Press R to reload</div>
    <div id="game-over"></div>
    <script src="./dist/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
function toggleMute() {
    let musicPlay;
    const audio = document.getElementsByTagName('audio');
    if (musicPlay == true) {
        musicPlay = false;
        // audio.muted;
        audio.pause;
        // return musicPlay;
    } else {
        musicPlay = true;
        !audio.muted;
        audio.play;
        // return musicPlay;
    }
    return musicPlay;
}
```

```
function setupKeyboardControls() {
    document.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
        console.log(e.keyCode);
        if (e.keyCode === 37) {
            moveLeft();
        } else if (e.keyCode === 38) {
            moveUp();
        } else if (e.keyCode === 39) {
            moveRight();
        } else if (e.keyCode === 40) {
            moveDown();
        } else if (e.keyCode === 82) {
            window.location.reload();
        } else if (e.keyCode === 77) {
            toggleMute();
        }
        screenLevel();
        screenScore();
        doorUnlock();
        levelChange();
        eraseMap();
        drawMap();
        gameOver();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Two issues with this as far as I can see:

1. `document.getElementsByTagName('audio')` will return an [HTML-collection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection), an array-like object of matched elements, even if only one matches. You should target `document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0]`.
2. `musicPlay` is intialised as an undefined variable each time `toggleMute` is called, so it will always be false. You should move that variable into the scope above `toggleMute`.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you use let `musicPlay` as global variable. Should hopefully fix the problem.

Also, try to make something like a `main()` function where you call `setupKeyboardControls` and other functions you need. Something like that:

```
function main(){

   let var1, var2, var3
   let players = [];
   let musicPlay = false

   setupKeyboard();
   toggleMusic();

} 

main();
```

And so on.